# Architecture vs Design patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

Someone in an interview asked me "What is the difference between architecture and design patterns?" In the discussion I unknowingly said that design patterns form the basis for a good architecture.

Is my assumption correct? Which one is the superset of the two?

Comment: Also note that Architecture also deals with the **Business Logic** & **analysis** of the application. Moreover architecture deals with the actual flow & solutions of the application's **ecosystem** e.g. Users, Moderators, Administrators, Terminals, User Access, Optimization solutions (Caching, DataStores), Products of use (eg in Database, NoSQL or RDBMS - MongoDB||MySQL) and many other.

Answer (score 2):

**Architecture** - sets which functionality the system should perform, split the functionality between components, set how components should behave and communicate in the system context, set the physical location of components and finally choose the tools in order to create components.

**Design** - while architecture deals more with the wide picture, design should drill down in to the details relating to implementing certain components. Designing of components end up with classes, interfaces, abstract classes and other OO feature in order to fulfill the given component tasks.

Comment: The question is about *design patterns,* not just 'design'.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the relation is that **Structural design patterns** can act as building blocks of a well designed **software architecture**.

Answer (score 1):

Architecture in my opinion relates to the way you will organize your components. Example 2 tier or 2 tier architecture. Design patterns solves common problems related to coding issues. A good architecture will make use of useful/appropriate Design Patterns. I guess you are correct.